# textCapSentences does not capitalize the input text

Tags: c#, android, android-edittext, mvvmcross, android-mvvm

I am developing app for android in Xamarin and MVVMCross. As seen below in the code, the Edittext UI-component is bound to UserInstanceId attribute.

What I am trying to do is, to force the user to enter max. 3 characters and all the character must be automatically capitalized, that's why I added 
the following line

```
   android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
```

but when the user inputs the texts, it never gets automatically capitalized.

can you please tell me why textCapSentences. does not work??

Note:i am testing on the emulator.

**code**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginView_editText_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edittext_margin_start"
            android:hint="@string/login_screen_user_id_hint"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            app:MvxBind="Text UserInstanceId"
            style="@style/edit_text_style"/>
```

Comment: you are testing it on emulator or a real device ?

Comment: @Umair on emulator

Comment: have you tried setting it pragmatically . ? and try adding `android:textAllCaps="true"`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `android:textAllCaps="true"` too in your `edittext` xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginView_editText_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edittext_margin_start"
        android:hint="@string/login_screen_user_id_hint"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        app:MvxBind="Text UserInstanceId"
        style="@style/edit_text_style"/>
```